# MediaWiki, Error: Class 'Wikimedia\Equivset\Equivset' not found

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I've updated mediawiki to the 1.38.2 version and I get the following error. I'm not very expert with PHP. Any hint would be appreciated.

```
/index.php?title=Cosa&action=submit Error: Class 'Wikimedia\Equivset\Equivset' not found

Backtrace:

from /extensions/AbuseFilter/includes/ServiceWiring.php(121)
#0 /vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(447): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer::{closure}()
#1 /vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(416): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService()
#2 /includes/MediaWikiServices.php(294): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService()
#3 /vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(424): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService()
#4 /extensions/AbuseFilter/includes/ServiceWiring.php(286): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->get()
#5 /vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(447): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer::{closure}()
#6 /vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(416): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService()
#7 /includes/MediaWikiServices.php(294): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService()
#8 /vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(424): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService()
#9 /vendor/wikimedia/object-factory/src/ObjectFactory.php(211): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->get()
#10 /vendor/wikimedia/object-factory/src/ObjectFactory.php(152): Wikimedia\ObjectFactory\ObjectFactory::getObjectFromSpec()
#11 /includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(473): Wikimedia\ObjectFactory\ObjectFactory->createObject()
#12 /includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(156): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->getHandlers()
#13 /includes/HookContainer/HookRunner.php(1468): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->run()
#14 /includes/editpage/Constraint/EditFilterMergedContentHookConstraint.php(89): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookRunner->onEditFilterMergedContent()
#15 /includes/editpage/Constraint/EditConstraintRunner.php(88): MediaWiki\EditPage\Constraint\EditFilterMergedContentHookConstraint->checkConstraint()
#16 /includes/EditPage.php(2280): MediaWiki\EditPage\Constraint\EditConstraintRunner->checkConstraints()
#17 /includes/EditPage.php(1694): EditPage->internalAttemptSave()
#18 /includes/EditPage.php(671): EditPage->attemptSave()
#19 /includes/actions/EditAction.php(71): EditPage->edit()
#20 /includes/actions/SubmitAction.php(38): EditAction->show()
#21 /includes/MediaWiki.php(543): SubmitAction->show()
#22 /includes/MediaWiki.php(321): MediaWiki->performAction()
#23 /includes/MediaWiki.php(912): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#24 /includes/MediaWiki.php(563): MediaWiki->main()
#25 /index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#26 /index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#27 {main}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`equivset` is a dependency of *MediaWiki*. Looks like it is not installed. Try `composer update` in *MediaWiki* folder.

Comment: It worked but I had to execute composer update in a subfolder (extensions/AbuseFilter). Why composer update in the main window doesn't extend to all subfolders? :/

Comment: run _../mediawiki/extensions/AbuseFilter# composer update_ solved also my _'Wikimedia\Equivset\Equivset' not found_ problem. Thanks for reporting your solution!

Comment: @Revious Now how did you figure that out?? Good Job!

Comment: @grantiago: yes thanks, now I'm working on mantaining an abandoned MW extension. I'd love to find some help...